# LINQ to SQL generates a different query for similar group by expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I noticed that when using GroupBy in Linq to SQL, there's a difference in the result query when providing a reference Id as the Key versus using the actual navigation property as the Key.

### Example 1:

`Employees.GroupBy(x => x.CompanyId).Select(g => g.Count())`

Result SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Employees] AS [t0]
GROUP BY [t0].[CompanyId]
```

### Example 2:

`Employees.GroupBy(x => x.Company).Select(g => g.Count())`

Result SQL:

```
SELECT [t1].[value]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[DivisionDeductionID]
    FROM [CheckDeductions] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[DivisionDeductionID]
) AS [t1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DivisionDeductions] AS [t2] ON [t2].[DivisionDeductionID] = [t1].[DivisionDeductionID]
```

Looking at Example #2, it is obvious that [t2] is never used other than the LEFT JOIN itself. why doesn't LINQ to SQL detects that and just uses the same query as Example #1? it anyways groups by the ID field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like EF's SQL generator has missed an opportunity to optimize the query: indeed, since `[t2]` is not used outside the outer join, it could be thrown away, along with a nested `select`.

It appears that EF writers added a join for `[t2]` because they did not want to differentiate between a situation (1) when a navigation property is used only for its PK (so the corresponding FK could be used in its place) and (2) a situation when the query actually pull additional fields from it.

This practice is completely justified, given that RDBMS optimizes out the unnecessary join anyway.